# How to prevent my Include() statement from populating the included entity's collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF Core 2.1, **database first approach**. I'm trying to Include() a foreign key entity when fetching my target entity collection, but something strange is happening.

The entity structure is Job -> JobStatus. I'm fetching some Job entities, and want to include the Job's JobStatus foreign key property. **The issue is that the JobStatus entity has a ICollection[Job] property that is populating every single Job from the database.** This is causing the payload to be gigabytes in size.

When I include the JobStatus on the Job, I'd like to satisfy one of the following solutions. I'm also open to other solutions or workarounds I haven't thought of.
*how can I prevent the JobStatus' ICollection property from populating? 
*Or can I prevent Entity Framework from generating that property in the first place?

### I've already explored Ignoring the ReferenceLoopHandling

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

### Here are the entities, automatically generated by Entity Framework.

```
public partial class Job
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long StatusId { get; set; }

    public JobStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public partial class JobStatus
{
    public JobStatus()
    {
        Job = new HashSet<Job>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Job> Job { get; set; }
}
```

### Example code that is causing the problem

```
var jobs = _context.Set<Job>()
    .Where(job => job.Id == 1)
    .Include(job => job.Status);
```

Comment: You should actually avoid having `public ICollection<Job> Job { get; set; }` in `JobStatus` class. That will not be useful in normal use cases and it will be harmful in terms of data retrieval as you are seeing now.

Comment: @Chetan How do I prevent Entity Framework from creating that property? I'm using database first. It would be a pain to manually remove all the offending properties in all generated classes every time I refresh the models. And a team member may forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid the Job collection from being populated is to explicitly select the columns that you want returned, either through a defined or anonymous type:

```
var jobs = _context.Set<Job>()
    .Where(job => job.Id == 1)
    .Include(job => job.Status)
    .Select(job => new
    {
        Id = job.Id,
        StatusName = job.Status.Name
    });
```

Comment: I will try this! I wish there was a clean EF way to solve my problem, but this seems like an okay workaround for now. I'll give it a shot soon.

Answer (score 1):

Add a "virtual" keyword. Any virtual ICollections will be lazy-loaded unless you specifically mark them otherwise.

```
public virtual ICollection<Job> Job { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell Entity Framework to make these properties virtual? I'm using a database first approach.